# Is having an HTTP service as an external authorization service supported in istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have seen example for EnvoyFilter in ISTIO where `grpc_service` is supported as filterconfig for external service call out.

```
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: ext-authz
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  filters:
  - insertPosition:
      index: FIRST
    listenerMatch:
      listenerType: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listenerProtocol: HTTP
    filterType: HTTP
    filterName: "envoy.ext_authz"
    filterConfig:
      grpc_service:
        google_grpc:
          target_uri: 127.0.0.1:9191
          stat_prefix: "ext_authz"
```

But I want to use my external service as filterconfig using **http_service** instead of **grpc_service** but everytime I get `404 not found` error.

Is `http_service` supported as `filterConfig` in Istio's `envoyFilter`?

version info : GKE is 14 and istio is 1.1.17

Comment: Can You check which version of envoy is Your Istio using? [Instructions to check version](https://archive.istio.io/v1.1/help/ops/misc/#what-envoy-version-is-istio-using)

Comment: ```"version": "4157a97bd82940cff8f775c42ac00c5219d5609b/1.11.0-dev/Clean/RELEASE/BoringSSL"```

Answer (score 1):

**Update: modified entire answer**.

After further verification it appears that Istio had `http_service` authorization service in the past it was not fully functional.

There were attempts to implement external HTTP service authorization for older versions of Istio, however it did work and the only workaround solutions were to use http lua filter or Nginx-Ingress Controller as Ingress Gateway that delegates the authentication part.

All of above cases can be found in [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13819) github issue. The HTTP call was successful but the headers were not being passed.

[Here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/9097) is another attempt in running `http_service` as authorization service.

---

As You noticed the [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.11.0/configuration/http_filters/ext_authz_filter.html?highlight=http_service#external-authorization) documentation for Envoy `1.11.0` `http_service` `filterConfig` has different syntax. Therefore I suggest trying the configuration for filter from the [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13819) issue. And if It doesnt't work, try the http lua filter as a workaround.

The HTTP service as an external authorization service its not mentioned in Istio documentation so, I think its safe to say its not fully supported.

Comment: This is the syntax for envoy installed. With istio-envoy where `kind=EnvoyFilter`, the syntax changes as I mentioned above. Does it make any difference?

Comment: @eshaingle I have edited my answer. After thorough verification the functionality of `http_service` is there but i wouldn't call it "supported" by istio.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to figure it out using http filter. We need to have correct cluster details, insert position and label to make it work.                           ` server_uri:
            cluster: outbound|8080||authz.svc.cluster.local
            timeout: 5s
            uri: http://authz.svc.cluster.local/
      filterName: envoy.ext_authz
      filterType: HTTP
      insertPosition:
        index: FIRST                                                                                                  
    workloadLabels:
       authz: enabled`

Comment: If my help was appreciated please upvote or accept the answer as it means a lot to me.